# Why the function doesn't return the value?

Tags: javascript, buckets

I have a javaScript function that use library Buckets and it should return the value to html.
I used console.log to see data inside the function and it's not null. But on the html, it said "undefined".

This is my js code :

```
function transformToStruct(xmlData) 
{
    var data = xmlData.item;
    var myReturn;
    $.getScript("buckets-minified.js", function() 
    {
        var treeData = new buckets.MultiDictionary();
        $.each(data, function(i,val) 
        {
            if(typeof data == 'object') 
            {
                $.each(val, function(j, childVal) 
                {
                    var dict = new buckets.Dictionary();
                    dict.set(val["NodeId"]["#text"], val["NodeText"]["#text"]);
                    treeData.set(val["ParentId"]["#text"], dict);

                });
            }
        });
        console.log(treeData)
        return treeData;        
    });
}
```

This is on the html page that I call transformToStruct function :

```
var myGTP = new buckets.MultiDictionary();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://frparlself6.dhcp.par.xxxx.corp:8000/com/sap/st/ltst/LTST_Backend/frontAccess/example.xsjs?structureId=" + structureId,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    type:'GET'
}).always(function() {      
    var sXml = _JSONFromHANA.body
    var xmlData = $.parseXML(sXml);
    var xml = xmlToJson(xmlData);
    var items = xml["soap-env:Envelope"]["soap-env:Body"]["n0:_-qte_-rfcReadStrucNodesResponse"]["EtNodes"];
    myGTP = transformToStruct(items);
    console.log(myGTP);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to understand asychronous calls and functions within functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`treeData` is the return value of an anonymous function that you pass as an argument to the function `getScript`. Your function `transformToStruct` doesn't actually have an own return value, so it's not surprising that it is `undefined`. Since `getScript` works asynchronously you could use a callback instead of a return value:

```
function transformToStruct(xmlData, callback) 
{
var data = xmlData.item;
var myReturn;
$.getScript("buckets-minified.js", function() 
{
    var treeData = new buckets.MultiDictionary();
    $.each(data, function(i,val) 
    {
        if(typeof data == 'object') 
        {
            $.each(val, function(j, childVal) 
            {
                var dict = new buckets.Dictionary();
                dict.set(val["NodeId"]["#text"], val["NodeText"]["#text"]);
                treeData.set(val["ParentId"]["#text"], dict);

            });
        }
    });
    console.log(treeData)
    callback(treeData);        
});
}
```

Your function call would then look like this:

```
var myGTP = new buckets.MultiDictionary();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://frparlself6.dhcp.par.xxxx.corp:8000/com/sap/st/ltst/LTST_Backend/frontAccess/example.xsjs?structureId=" + structureId,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    type:'GET'
}).always(function() {      
    var sXml = _JSONFromHANA.body
    var xmlData = $.parseXML(sXml);
    var xml = xmlToJson(xmlData);
    var items = xml["soap-env:Envelope"]["soap-env:Body"]["n0:_-qte_-rfcReadStrucNodesResponse"]["EtNodes"];
    transformToStruct(items, function(result) {
        myGTP = result;
        console.log(myGTP);
    });

});
```

But as mentioned in the comments, you should probably read something about asynchronous functions first.

Comment: I've never known about asynchronously before. I'm so new in javaScript and jQuery. Thanks a lot.